# Routes handling in go

Tags: http, express, go, routes

In express you can handle any routes by doing this

```
app.get('/*', dosomething..)
```

I've tried doing the same in go but it doesn't seem to be working

```
http.Handle("/*", http.FileServer(http.Dir("../client/dist")))
```

Comment: @yageek is right - remove "*" after slash. Also - is your server running?

Comment: Yes, my server is running. it handles all routes without the asterisk, but the problem now is that I'm using react's client-side rendering and the app brakes when I try to manually type in the URL, or refresh the page. In express I would send the index.html file and serve the dist folder with a middleware to solve this. Is there a way to do the same in go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read closely the documentation of [http.ServeMux](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeMux),  the slash `/` matches all routes.

Simply writes:

```
http.Handle(“/“, MyHandler)
```